# Unable to type in a terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, cursor, xfce4-terminal

When I open a terminal no cursor appears, and no text, I just get a blank black screen. I am able to run commands by pressing Ctrl-Alt-F2.

I have minimal understanding of typing code etc. (Using Ubuntu 14.04 with Xfce interface.) Thank you if you're able to help.

Comment: Is this just in the graphical terminal? Or is it other apps as well?

Comment: What happens if you press a `Ctrl+C` after opening the terminal? Does the prompt appear?

Comment: Nothing happened with Ctrl+C. Yes, just the graphical terminal as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I have no prompt in terminal on XFCE in ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/280896/why-do-i-have-no-prompt-in-terminal-on-xfce-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Terminal and go to "Profile preferences" from main Edit menu in Terminal and check below configuration:

[image]

"Text color" and "Background color" with different color and also if you don't want custom color click on "Use colors from system theme" check box and then click close.

Comment: Wonderful! It worked, and such a simple solution. "Use colors from the system theme" was ticked (with no indication of what colors were being used for what), so I unticked that and chose white text on black background, which now appears. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this cursor visible issue, please open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and use the following command.

gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false

After executing the above command please check whether the cursor issue resolved. If still this issue persist, go to "settings - displays - disable unknown display".

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal go to -> edit -> Preferences -> Command 
Select only checkbox 
(checked) Run command as a login shell 
(Remove check) Run a custom command instead of my shell

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Terminal
2. Edit option -> Preferences
3. Under Command tab select checkbox with option "Run command a a login Shell" and uncheck other options.
4. Restart the command